# Newbie: php sqli_connect fails

Tags: php

i´m pretty new to php and i have encountered a problem with no idea where it comes from. 
I want to connect to an sql-db via php in order to access this via iOS. But the first step fails allready :(
This is a screenshot with login data from my provider:

[image: Provider]

Then i uploaded this php to the website:

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("db559233526.db.1and1.com","dbo559233526","Correct Password","db559233526");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
// This SQL statement selects ALL from the table ‚Cards‘
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Cards";
// Check if there are results
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
// If so, then create a results array and a temporary one
// to hold the data
$resultArray = array();
$tempArray = array();
// Loop through each row in the result set
while($row=$result->fetch_object())
{
    // Add each row into our results array
    $tempArray = $row;
    array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
}
// Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results
echo json_encode($resultArray);
}
// Close connections
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

You con see the result here:
http://sektor3d.de/service.php

Now i wonder, why the last half of the code is shown as text? And why is the "break" at that point?
Thanks for help or any idea!

Comment: That makes no sense, and should never happen... The only thing I can think of is if the upload has been corrupted or someone is messing with someone ;)

Comment: your server support PHP?

Comment: hi. yes, php seems to be running. I uploaded a info.php as Simone requested in his answer. http://sektor3d.de/info.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check if your server support PHP**

Create a file (in any text editor) and inside the file type:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Save it as `info.php`

Upload it to your server, and then, in your web browser, navigate to that file eg. http://sektor3d.de/info.php

Comment: Hi and thanks, i did so and u can see the result here http://sektor3d.de/info.php - seems php 5.5.20 is running.

Comment: try to open WITH block notes and save service.php with ANSI encode

Comment: Thanks a lot! I saved it with Win Editor and now its working! Previously i did it with OSX Textedit :(

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your page source, your server seems to not be able to run PHP. If you're convinced it can, add this code to your `.htaccess` file:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Comment: Thanks, i did so but without any effect :( the .htaccess now looks so:    `AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php3 .php4 .php .phtml
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php`